# Dynamic Variables With PowerQuery

Tags: postgresql, parameters, odbc, excel-2013, powerquery

I have a table on my workbook that looks like below

> Parameter   Value
>     salestart   01/01/2016
>     saleend     01/21/2016

And I am trying to query a postgresql database and use the value for salestart and saleend in the where clause.  I am just stuck on how to get the syntax perfect to achieve such a result.  This is what I have thus far, but I get an error of:

> ODBC escape convert error

And this is the actual syntax I am attempting.  What must I alter so that this will be a valid statement and return the data I am needing?

```
let
Parameter = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Parameters"]}[Content],
txtsalestart = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Parameter,{{"salestart", type text}}),
txtsaleend = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Parameter,{{"saleend", type text}}),
Source = Odbc.Query("dsn=123", "Select * from saledb AND CAST(saledate As Date) BETWEEN between '"&#"txtsalestart" & "'" AND '"&#"txtsaleend" & "'#(lf)ORDER BY saleitem ASC")
```

in
    Source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query value is not built correctly: `"'" AND '"` should be `"' AND '"`